# getaddrinfo() fails when attempting to download a stream

Tags: c, sockets, url, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to download a few seconds from a livestream using sockets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* close() */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sock;
    char host[] = "http://141.138.89.176/fun-1-44-128";
    char port[] = "80";
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    char message[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: http://141.138.89.176/fun-1-44-128";
    unsigned int i;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;
    int status;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    status = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
    if (status != 0) {
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        return 1;
    }
    sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    status = connect(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if (status == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        return 1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);

    do {
        bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
        if (bytes_read == -1) {
            perror("recv");
        }
        else {
            printf("%.*s", bytes_read, buf);
        }
    } while (bytes_read > 0);

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, however when running, `getaddrinfo()` fails.  I assume that this means that the host cannot be found.

This is my url: http://141.138.89.176/fun-1-44-128
It works in my browser so I don't know what's going on.  Could anyone shed some light on the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code on my environment and it's perfectly working so your code is surely okay. I recommend checking your compiler, maybe reinstall it.

EDIT: Okay I think I found the problem. It was that the host should only be the ip address, not the full link.

(also added a fix to the error reporting from getaddrinfo)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* close() */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sock;
    char host[] = "141.138.89.176";
    char port[] = "80";
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    char message[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: 141.138.89.176/fun-1-44-128";
    unsigned int i;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;
    int status;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    status = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
    if (status != 0) {
    printf("Code: %d\n", status);
    printf("Message: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }
...
```

Comment: It runs properly and compiles properly, however there is no stream data printed.   perror("getaddrinfo"); triggers and I don't understand why.

Comment: Name or service not known, this is the error message by the status. The status runs to -2.

Comment: thank you, I found out what was wrong.  I only pass the top level IP to `getaddrinfo()`, if I want a subdirectory I have to pass it in the subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured out the solution.

`getaddrinfo()` *only* accepts base host names, domain names or ip addresses, with **no** subdirectories.

This means that 192.168.0.4, [www.site.com](http://www.site.com), localhost are all valid.  192.168.0.4/Search, [www.site.com/Search](http://www.site.com/Search), localhost/Search are not.

You also don't need to include the scheme.  Sockets don't differentiate http from https, it's how requests are dealt with makes the difference.

You need to change `host` so that it only contains the IP address.

What you want is:

```
char host[] = "141.138.89.176";
```

You won't get that error now.

If you want to access a subdirectory you pass it as a `GET` request.  It's actually the web server that handles file and directory stuff.  The base IP stays the same.

First off your formatting is wrong.  It should be `\r\n` and `\r\n\n\n` to finish.  It should look like this: `char message[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 141.138.89.176/fun-1-44-128\r\n\n\n";`

Now if you try this, you will get a 400 error.  this is because it's incorrectly written.  Much like the above `Host` only accepts the base url/ip.  See that `/` right after the `GET`?  That's where you request any subdirectories/files you want.  The `/` you have there now indicates that you want the top level dictionary.

It should look like this:

```
message[] = "GET /fun-1-44-128 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 141.138.89.176\r\n\n\n";
```